# Understanding sed regex pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I'm very new to the Linux World and I'm trying to get a hang of the basic commands. While going thru one of the scripts, observed the below line, which I couldn't comprehend.

```
sed -n -e 's|declare -x ||p' -e 's|^declare -ax* \([^=]*\)='\''\(.*\)'\''.*$|\1=\2|p'
```

Going thru the SED & declare man pages, i got an idea about the flags/options, like -n and -e, but not sure about the regex like pattern given above and what exactly "p" at the end of the command does ?

Tried to reproduce the above line on the regex101 site, but with no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first expression simply removes any `declare -x`.

The second extracts the variable and value from `declare -ax variable=value` with some complications around quoting.  The `x` is optional (strictly speaking the regex allows zero or more, but you probably don't expect more than one).

In some more detail,

- `s|regex|replacement|` just replaces any match of `regex` with `replacement`, using `|` as the regex delimiter instead of the default `/`
- `s|regex|replacement|p` with the `p` flag prints the resulting line if the replacement occurred; this is often combined with `sed -n` to only print the lines where a replacement occurred.
- `'whatever'\''something'\''more stuff'` uses shell quoting to represent literal single quotes in an otherwise single-quoted string.  You can't escape single quotes inside single quotes so this uses a closing single quote followed by a backslashed literal single quote followed by another opening single quote to embed single quotes in the quoted string.
- `s/\(something.*\)other/\1/` replaces `something or other` with `something or`, where the backslashed parentheses specify grouping, and `\1` is a back reference to the text which matched the first parenthesized group.  Similarly `\2` refers to the second parenthesized group, etc.

`.*` inside the parentheses is actually wrong if the intent is to capture a single-quoted string; the regex should only match a character which is not a single quote (or ideally an expression which contains literal single quotes as per the explanation above).

https://regex101.com/ is not particularly suitable for `sed` regex. It doesn't support the regex dialect of `sed` (the closest is probably the ECMAScript dialect, but you have to understand the differences anyway), and can't tell you what the surrounding script does.

Comment: To get an idea of how Basic (BRE) and Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) are used in sed, the manual has [this overview](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions-Overview)

Answer (score 1):

The `p` is a flag of the `s` command. On my system, it's not documented in the `man` page, but in the `info` page.

> 'p' 
> If the substitution was made, then print the new pattern space.

The `'\''` dance is just a common way how to insert a single quote into a bash parameter. Single quotes are removed during "quote removal" and single quotes can't be nested. So you need to end the quoted string, escape a quote, and start another quoted string. You can also find the alternative `'"'"'` in the wild.

The sed will therefore see this as the parameter (I used the traditional `/` instead of `|` as there's no need to use `|`):

```
s/^declare -ax* \([^=]*\)='\(.*\)'.*$/\1=\2/p
```

which searches for `declare` at the beginning of a line (`^`) followed by a space, `-a` and possibly `x` or `xx` or `xxx` etc.; followed by a space and anything but `=`, then `=`, and then really anything in single quotes. We don't care what follows the last single quote. The two anythings are remembered in `\1` and `\2`, and the whole line is replaced by `\1=\2`, i.e. the `declare -axxx`  is removed from it, as are the outermost single quotes. If the line doesn't match the regex, nothing is printed.

Comment: The `sed` command will actually remove any single quotes around the string it extracts from `declare -a` -- I actually thought that was its main purpose really.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, I noticed while still editing the answer :-)